# Find all local maximum and minimum points

Tags: calculus

$F(x)=1$   if the decimal expansion of $x $ contains a $5$; $=0$ otherwise.

According to the answer, $x$ is a local minimum point if its decimal expansion does not contain 5.

If I understand the question correctly, if $x$’s decimal expansion does not contain $5$, $x$ should be $0$ and every number around it should also be $0$ unless $x$ is $.49999\cdots999$ So the correct answer should be either local minimum or both a local minimum and a local maximum

[image]

Comment: $F(x)$ is a piecewise function assuming only two values: $F(x)=1$ when the decimal expansion of $x$ contains a 5, and $F(x)=0$ otherwise. Since $F(x)$ does not assume any other value, *every x which does not have 5 in its decimal expansion serves as a local minimum, and every x which does serves as a local maximum.*

Comment: There is a third option. Every x is both a maximum and a minimum no?

Comment: I don't think a value from the domain can simultaneously be a local minimum and maximum. Why would you think it can be both?

Comment: For the situation where x is a horizontal line

Comment: From page 635 answer of calculus:Michael Slovak edition: in all other cases, x is both a local maximum and a local minimum

Comment: I guess you're referring to Spivak's Calculus? I'll look into the exact context and add an answer once I understand your point of confusion.

Comment: @Manan yes, Spivak. Thank you so so much

Answer (score 1):

As elaborated by you in the comments, I looked up for the exact question and solution provided in Spivak's Calculus, 3rd Edition. Perhaps the way the solution was phrased(for the sake of compactness) confused you. Here's the solution:

> $x$ is a local maximum(minimum) point if the decimal expansion contains(does not contain) a 5.

This simply means **that for every $x$ containing a 5 in its decimal expansion, the function acquires a local maximum(=1), and for every $x$ not containing a 5, the function acquires a local minimum(=0).**

Furthermore, *a point cannot serve as a local minimum and maximum simultaneously.* I suggest you to go through the Calculus 1 course on [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org).

Comment: Very strange. I have the 4th edution and there seesm to be some change.

Comment: @jxhyc I find the solution in 4th edition to be quite baffling. I've always seen Spivak as the gold-standard Calculus textbook so I wouldn't expect an error like this one. I'll pass and upvote the question for now. Maybe an expert can enlighten me as well.